# The DataSourceID of 'DataListCity' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource. A control with ID 'SqlDataSource1' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I get this error on the page when I try to display the page in browser

The `DataSourceID` of `DataListCity` must be the ID of a control of type `IDataSource`.

And get this error.

> A control with ID SqlDataSource1 could not be found.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The DataSourceID of
>   'DataListCity' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource.  A
>   control with ID 'SqlDataSource1' could not be found.

Here is the code in my Masterpage that is causing the error :

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListCity" runat="server" Width="100%"                 
onitemcommand="DataListCity_ItemCommand"                                    
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333">
<ItemTemplate>
CityId:                                                                              
<asp:Label ID="CityIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CityId") %>' />                                                             
<br />
CityName:                                                                     
<asp:Label ID="CityNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CityName") %>' />
<br />
<br />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the definition of asp:SqlDataSource. The error clearly states that. You can view an example and details on DataList and SqlDataSource here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603s5x0%28v=vs.85%29.aspx